Dependency's deployment target in lower than Xcode's minimum deployment target on .podspec
I am trying to host a private pod for my project but when I run 'pod spec lint' it gives error like '- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.'. I think it is caused by the minimum version mis-match from xcode. Here is one of the errors it is providing "- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.4.99. (in target 'CGRPCZlib' from project 'Pods')".

Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  spec.name         = "app-service-ios"
  spec.version      = "0.0.2"
  spec.summary      = "###summary"
  spec.homepage     = "###homepage url"
  spec.author       = { "###email" }
  spec.source       = { :git => "###git link", :tag => spec.version.to_s }
  spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  spec.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
  spec.swift_version = '5.0'
  spec.source_files  = 'Classes/*.grpc.swift'

  spec.dependency 'SwiftProtobuf', '1.26.0'
  spec.dependency 'gRPC-Swift'

end


Here is my .podpsec file.
I am using Xcode 15.3 which has a minimum deployment target on iOS 12.0.
If it was error on 'pod install' I could just changed the dependency's minimum deployment version on the 'post_install'. But how do you do it in .podspec?

Ask the owners of CGRPCZlib to update it.
